# Chromecast With TV - Timer with Pyton?

Tags: python, timer, chromecast, profile, television

Did anybody had luck configuring a profile timer on Chromecast With TV via a Python script?

I'd like to remotely control the amount of time available for an specific Chromecast profile.

Thank you!
e.